# Have both scrollbar buttons at bottom in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, themes, scrolling

I want to have both of my scrollbar buttons at the bottom like the way it is on a mac. How can I do this in Ubuntu? I know some themes support it but I was wondering if there was a way to make this permanent for all themes.

Comment: i think what you're describing is set by the theme, so to do it for all themes you'd need to modify all themes.  (this is why some themes are configured this way and some aren't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "scrollbar-arrows" {
    GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 0
    GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 1
    GtkScrollbar::has-secondary-backward-stepper = 1
    GtkScrollbar::has-secondary-forward-stepper = 0
}
class "GtkScrollbar" style "scrollbar-arrows"
```

*...do people really use those buttons these days?*

Comment: I don't have that on my system.

Comment: @Lucas: If you use Nautilus, press Ctrl+H to show all hidden files, if you still can't find it, jsut create it with the content from grawity. Logout/Login might be required for the chances to take effect.

Comment: This "new" default setting with the arrows at the bottom just made me crazy. With your help and suggestions I was able to do the reverse and put the arrows back at top and bottom again!

Comment: I use scrollbar arrows, and have devoted days and days to my desperate struggle to enable them.  Your answer here days provide them for the Pale Moon web browser, which is a significant step in the right direction, but so far I cannot obtain scroll arrows either in the Terminal or in the Blue Fish text editor.